# An inexplicable error class error in my application

Tags: delphi-5

I have a major problem and I have no idea how it might be corrected.   Out of the blue, when I compile then try to run my application - which I have been working on for six months - I get a `Class Not Registered` error.   I also have a pop-up error message saying that `dbx.dbl` was not found.   I have added nothing to the program in the past few days which included any new classes.  I am using Delphi 5.  I do not know how to identify which class is not registered.  The program will not run and I have spent hours trying to track down the problem without success.

More information:  I have moved the executable and data files to another computer, and it all runs fine.   So it seems to be a problem with my development box.

More Information:   I did as fpiette suggested but found nothing which helped. So I created a very basic application:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, Db, ADODB;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ADOConnection1.Connected := True;
   ADOQuery1.Close;
   ADOQuery1.Connection := ADOConnection1;
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from tblsupplier');
   ADOQuery1.Open;
end;

end.
```

The `Class Not Registered` error occurs when it executes the `ADOQuery1.Open;` line.

Am I right in assuming that since there are no other components in the program that the error must be in the `ADO` code?   The `ADOConnection1` points at an Access database called `Suppliers` and the connection test was successful.

Comment: It's a COM error. You need to register the COM server that is required. "out of the blue"??? You literally put the program on a new computer!

Comment: David, I understand that it's a COM error.   What I don't understand is why it suddenly wanted to include a COM class I hadn't specified.    And I don't understand which one it is (no information provided by the error) or where to look.    I put the executable and data files on a new computer, not the whole development environment.    That tells me that whatever the system is missing on the development machine is available on the new machine.   But I still don't know what.

Comment: Anything quarantined by your antivirus? Anything in the Windows event log?

Comment: Afraid not.   I haven't downloaded anything new for months.   I try to keep the development machine "clean".

Comment: It doesn't suddenly want to do anything. The old machine had the COM server registered. The new one does not.

Comment: Don't you mean this the other way round?   I cannot run the program on the development machine because the "class" is missing.   If I move the compiled executable to the new machine, it runs.    So the new machine has the class that Delphi is looking forward registered, but the development machine (suddenly) doesn't.   Or am I missing something?   It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Try running the program under the dbugger and step one line at a time to find where the error message is triggered (maybe right on the first line, use F7 to start the program).

Comment: Thanks fpiette, I did as you suggested.   The component it cannot find is created in a unit called about.pas, but the compiler/linker cannot find this unit.    This must be part of a component, but I cannot tell from the previous calls where it comes from.   The unit the system processed immediately before hitting this error was gifimage.pas, but there is no call to about.pas in that unit.   I've not used the debugger before.  How do you move from line to line after starting the program using F7 please?

Comment: Read the documentation to learn about the debugger

Comment: I have done that and have run the debugger successfully but it does not tell me where the error line is called from - or I am not reading the data correctly.   Please see the additional information in my original question.

Comment: It is a corruption of some sort in the ADO module.   I've loaded Delphi onto another machine and everything works just fine.    Will have to reload Delphi on to the development machine.   Can I close this thread?